# How do I test Throttling using SOAP UI?

Tags: rest, soapui, load-testing, throttling

I'm pretty new to Soap UI and I'm wondering if someone might know how to configure a Throttling service in SOAP UI.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean load testing? Have you tried [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/Load-Testing/concept.html)?

Comment: Yes, I know how to set up the Load Ui for regular load testing but not sure how to do it for Throttling